# PHP - array return multiple result

Tags: php, arrays

I can't figure out workaround while working with array results in my Symfony project.

I got results like:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    0 => "name"
    1 => "info"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    0 => "Jack"
    1 => "Info One"
  ]
]
```

So, this part work just fine but I need to return multiple results for that INFO field. For the Name Jack I need to return Info One, Info Two, Info Three etc, but this way I only returns just first one..

This is what I tried:

```
public function getData($account)
{

    $invoice = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Transaction')->findBy([
        'account' => $account
    ]);
 $rows[] = array(
     "client",
     "info"
 );

 foreach ($invoice as $row) {
     $rows[] = array(
         $row->->getName(),
         $row->getInfo(),
     );
 }
```

And I want something like:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    0 => "name"
    1 => "info"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    0 => "Jack"
    1 => array:4 [▼
          0 => "Info One"
          1 => "Info Two"
          2 => "Info Three"
        ]
    ]
]
```

Any suggestions? Thanks guys.

Comment: Sorry, but that looks like horribly broken code. And if you want to append something to an inner key, why don't you do so? Obviously, you are attaching new rows in your loop

Comment: Where are the `Info Two` and `Info Three` ? Can you show the expected result ?

Comment: Your example array is too incomplete (thank you for trying to trim it down) for us to understand where "Info Two" etc would come from. Can you expand the example input array a bit more?

Comment: I updated my post. Thanks. @NicoHaase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's untested and a kind of draft...

```
public function getData($account)
{
    $invoices = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Transaction')->findBy([
       'account' => $account
    ]);

    $rows = [];

    /* set headers */
    $rows[] = [
        "client",
        "info"
    ];

    foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
        $name = $invoice->getName();
        $info = $invoice->getInfo();

        if (empty($rows[$name])) {
            $rows[$name] = [
                $name,
                [
                    $info
                ]
            ];
        } else {
            $rows[$name][1][] = $info;
        }
    );

    return $rows;
}
```

Comment: You saved me bro. Thank you a lot!  @Daniel